# Nested MIN within SUMIF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, min, sumifs

**Problem:** I can't seem to get the > `MIN` formula to work within `SUMIFS`

**Requesting:** Formula that will return the `SUM` of balloons `IF` the dollars amount is greater than the `MIN`

Expected output = 510,000 balloons

[image]

Note: This is just an example problem for easy comprehension. In reality the data set is much larger and I will include multiple `IF`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum the entire range and then just subtract the values from the range where the dollar amount is equal to the min $.

If your min value is repeated, they will all be removed from the sum.

```
=SUM(C:C) - SUMIF(B:B,MIN(B:B),C:C)
```

---

I believe you were attempting to do this in one sum equation which would look like this

```
=SUMIF(B:B,">"&MIN(B:B),C:C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B>MIN(B:B)),C:C)
```